# Relative paths in web.xml with Eclipse and appengine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, web.xml

I want to reference a local file for web-app_2_3.dtd in my web.xml file, but can't find a way to use a relative path.  Since this file is used on multiple machines the relative path is important.

I put the dtd file I want to use in the WEB-INF directory (with web.xml) and have tried to reference it with things like "web-app_2_3.dtd" and "war/WEB-INF/web-app_2_3.dtd" and every permutation and depth of things like that I can think of.

Is there a variable I can use to reference the war directory, or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that in the web.xml paths are relative to the webroot, so if its in the WEB-INF, the relative path would be something like `/WEB-INF/web-app_2_3.dtd` with no need for the war/ in front of it